# How can I use two databases in yii framework

Tags: php, yii, yii-components

I'm new to yii framework. I have two questions to ask :

1. I have to create tabs for each table in the database `test` under which I have to have the menu for the rows of the table. How can I do this.
2. For the application, I will be using the database `test`. But, for user login I will be using another database `user`. So, I need to use two databases.Currently, the skeleton application has only two usernames `admin` and `demo`. I need to retrieve many usernames from `user` table of `user` database. How can I do this in yii framework.

Answer (score 0):

in your `config.php` file under `components` you can define the two databases like this.

```
return array(
    ...
    'components' => array(
        'db' => array(
            'connectionString' => 'mysql:host=dbserver1;dbname=my1db',
            ...
        ),
        'dbuser' => array(
            'connectionString' => 'mysql:host=adserver2;dbname=advertisingDB',
            'username'         => 'advertuser',
            'password'         => '***********',
            ...
            'class'            => 'CDbConnection'        
        ),
```